# Добавление сразу 5 полей в базу MySQL

Tags: php

Есть задача, чтобы после регистрации у пользователя в пользовательской таблице появились пункты по умолчанию (допустим, 5 полей), а уже потом он сам сможет удалить старые или добавить новые поля.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, я уточню, вы же не собираетесь заводить таблицу под каждого пользователя, верно?

Comment: Надо создать таблицу типа user_data, куда будут заноситься id пользователя и его данные, можно сделать их отдельно, а можно сериализовать

Comment: спасибо реализовал проще =) выше приведу результат.

Comment: Чисто для общего развития и повышения скорости работы скрипта: оператор INSERT поддерживает добавления сразу нескольких строк:

    INSERT INTO `table` (`col_1`, `col_2`,...) VALUES (`val_1_1`, `val_1_2`, ...), (`val_2_1`, `val_2_2`, ...), ...

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

```
$lead_source  = array(
    array("title" => "Facebook", "parameter" => "fb", "background_color" => "#99CCFF"),
    array("title" => "Google", "parameter" => "gl", "background_color" => "#FFCC66"),
    array("title" => "Yandex", "parameter" => "ya", "background_color" => "#E9967A"),
    array("title" => "Vkontakte", "parameter" => "vk", "background_color" => "#87CEFA"),
    array("title" => "Mail.ru", "parameter" => "ml", "background_color" => "#FFE4B5"),
    array("title" => "Не определено", "parameter" => "none", "background_color" => "#FA8072"),
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($lead_source); $i++) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO traffic_source (title,parameter,background_color,id_klient) VALUES ('".$lead_source[$i]['title']."','".$lead_source[$i]['parameter']."','".$lead_source[$i]['background_color']."','".$myrow['user_id']."')");
}
```

---

Комментарий пользователя @fremail:

> Чисто для общего развития и повышения скорости работы скрипта:
>   оператор `INSERT` поддерживает добавления сразу нескольких строк:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (col_1, col_2,...) 
> VALUES (val_1_1, val_1_2, ...), (val_2_1, val_2_2, ...), ...
> ```